# Excel write function that checks next cell found value is 0

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need an `If` statement that moves on and checks next cell if the value is `< 0`. I have figured out how to get it to put all the values from another column that has the same rows as cells with the word "hello" in it. Here is that code:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$10000;SMALL(IF("hello"=$C$2:$C$10000;ROW($C$2:$C$10000)-ROW($C$2)+1);ROW(1:1)))
```

How can I wrap or put in an `if` statement that only lets takes values `> 0`?

The picture is my current state and it does everything I want except for the three zeros, the column marked is the one with the code stated above. I want to see how many of the sum of the two columns is bigger than 130 000 000, that answer should be 11. The 1s and 0s represent if the sum of the two most left columns is bigger than 130 000 000.

[image]

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the `AGGREGATE()` worksheet function?

Comment: Yes it does! How can I use that to not use the values when they are zero?

Comment: I might misunderstand your needs but if you want to count how many adjacent cells in column M and N together exceed 130M then you can use this array formula: `{=SUM(IF(M2:M10000+N2:N10000>130000000;1;0))}